# Logging the erronous ID but not breaking the LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Here is my problem. I am looping through some values and some of those values raise an exception. I want to log those values, but the program flow should not break. I mean, if I encounter such a value, I will simply log the error and skip to the next value.

here is the simplified version :

```
drop table test;
--destination Table
create table test
(
  id varchar2(2)
);
```

-- Error log table

```
create table test_log
(
  id varchar2(10)
);


DECLARE
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN 90..102
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO test
      VALUES (c);
    l_num:=c;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(l_num);
    INSERT INTO test_log 
      VALUES (l_num);
  COMMIT;
  --raise;
END;
/
```

My problem is, when it's encountering an error, it simply jumps to the exception section and not looping through the later values in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the exception in an inner block:

```
DECLARE
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN 90..102
  LOOP
    l_num:=c;
    BEGIN -- inner block
      INSERT INTO test
      VALUES (c);
    EXCEPTION -- in inner block
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(l_num);
        INSERT INTO test_log 
        VALUES (l_num);
    END; -- inner block
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The loop won't be interrupted if an exception occurs; only that single insert is affected. Note that you don't really want to commit inside the exception handler as that will commit all the successful inserts so far, not just the error. (If you wanted to log the errors but later roll back you could use an autonomous procedure to do the logging, but that's a separate discussion). And you don't want to re-raise the exception as that would still break the loop and the whole outer anonymous block.

Catching 'others' is generally not a good idea; if you have known errors you could encounter - like a bad data or number format - it's better to catch those explicitly. If you have a wider problem like not being able to extend a data file then the insert inside the exception handler would presumably fail anyway though.

You don't really need `l_num` any more as `c` is still in-scope for the inner exception handler, so you could simplify slightly to:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN 90..102
  LOOP
    BEGIN -- inner block
      INSERT INTO test
      VALUES (c);
    EXCEPTION -- in inner block
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(c);
        INSERT INTO test_log 
        VALUES (c);
    END; -- inner block
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply But i am not getting the intended outout. I should have got 100,101,102 in the table test_log as these are the values which are generating exceptions. Instead I am getting 
99
99
99
99

Comment: @AsfakulIslam - was that before I moved the `l_num := c` from after the insert (where you had it) to before it? It was being updated in the wrong place, which I think explains your 99 problem. You don't need `l_num` at all in this example though, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FORALL.

That answer to your request with SAVE EXCEPTION statement because  the FORALL loop to continue even if some DML operations fail. And it will be more efficient than a simple LOOP.

Ex :

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR LCUR$VAL IS
        SELECT ID
        FROM test1;
    TYPE LT$TAB      IS TABLE OF TEST%ROWTYPE;
    LA$TAB_TEST      LT$TAB;
    dml_errors       EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA           EXCEPTION_INIT(dml_errors, -24381);
    LC$ERRORS        NUMBER(11);
    LC$ERRNO         NUMBER(11);
    LC$MSG           VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR);
    LC$IDX           NUMBER(11);
BEGIN
    OPEN LCUR$VAL;
    LOOP
        FETCH LCUR$VAL BULK COLLECT INTO LA$TAB_TEST LIMIT 1000;
        BEGIN
            FORALL x IN 1 .. LA$TAB_TEST.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                INSERT INTO test VALUES LA$TAB_TEST(x);

                EXIT WHEN LCUR$VAL%NOTFOUND;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN DML_ERRORS THEN
                LC$ERRORS := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
                FOR idx IN 1 .. LC$ERRORS
                LOOP
                    LC$ERRNO    := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (idx).ERROR_CODE;
                    LC$MSG      := sqlerrm(-LC$ERRNO);
                    LC$IDX      := sql%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(idx).error_index;

                    -- here you can log in table : test_log...
                END LOOP;
        END;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE LCUR$VAL;
END;
```

Hoping that it can help.

Comment: To be honest, you are overcomplicating things a little bit. In OP's case, you can simply use `log errors reject limit unlimited` clause of the `insert` statement to get the job done. P.S. The error logging table needs to be created beforehand using `dbms_errlog.create_error_log` procedure.